# SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD) only yields first event, sequential events

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

From a .net application I wish to capture all keyboard events, globally.

I set a callback using a win32-method `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, HINSTANCE)`. (Using dllimport and some mashall-call.)

One the first key is pressed I get a nice response saying which key is pressed.
My callback-function calls `CallNextHookEx` as is should do.
But after the first event I get no more events.

Any-one has any idea of common causes for events to stop coming?

Comment: The most common cause would be a bug in your code.

Comment: @Erik, not really ... see my answer.

Comment: I haven't build that functionality myself, instead I used this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: I actually tried using that library too. However then I got a different problem. On my Win7-64bit two-stroke-keys, like ü û ñ started to fail, becoming ¨u, ^u and ~n.
But that is probably a different question...

Comment: one thing you should watch out for though is that from personal experience most of the places people use WH_KEYBOARD_LL they get it wrong, either they do not service the requests fast enough or the thread servicing it dies or the cross context stuff just randomly plays up. I would would go unmanged here if I wanted something very robust with minimal impact. injecting a dll or a device driver are both options that are lighter weight perf wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WH_KEYBOARD` is not supported from a managed wrapper, it needs to inject itself into the process.

You can use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` which will be called in the declaring thread.

see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

> Global hooks are not supported in the
>   .NET Framework Except for the
>   WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the
>   WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot
>   implement global hooks in the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework. To install a
>   global hook, a hook must have a native
>   DLL export to inject itself in another
>   process that requires a valid,
>   consistent function to call into. This
>   behavior requires a DLL export. The
>   .NET Framework does not support DLL
>   exports. Managed code has no concept
>   of a consistent value for a function
>   pointer because these function
>   pointers are proxies that are built
>   dynamically.
>
> Low-level hook procedures are called
>   on the thread that installed the hook.
>   Low-level hooks do not require that
>   the hook procedure be implemented in a
>   DLL.

Answer (score 1):

If your hook callback function takes too long to return, windows will stop calling it to preserve system performance. Try just a simple call to OutputDebugString and CallNextHookEx and see if that helps...

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately my logging claims it only takes a few ms. So there must be some other thing causing this.